# Herança com Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, npgsql

Estou com uma duvida na parte de herança, tenho as classes pessoa e usuário. Pessoa tem seus atributos básicos e o usuário herda da pessoa. Até ai tudo bem está certo.

Meu problema esta que no mapeamento do contexto estou passando o usuário, mas não gostaria que criasse todos os campos da pessoa no banco de dados, então como posso limitar quais campos quero que seja criado no banco ? ou não existe como.

Classe Pessoa

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;


namespace Model
{
    public class Pessoa
    {
        private int codigo;
        private int status; // Ativo = 1, Inativo = 0
        private string nome;
        private string email;
        private string cidade;
        private string endereco;
        private string bairro;
        private string numero;
        private DateTime dtCriacao;

        //Contrutor para heranca para obrigacao da criacao de usuario
        public Pessoa( string nome, string email, int status) {
            this.nome  = nome;
            this.email = email;
            this.status = status;
            this.dtCriacao = DateTime.Now;
        }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Data Criaçao deve estar preenchida")]
        public DateTime DtCriacao
        {
            get { return dtCriacao; }
            set { dtCriacao = value; }
        }


        [Key]
        public int Codigo
        {
            get { return codigo; }
            set { codigo = value; }
        }

        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Status deve estar entre 1 = Ativo ou 0 = Inativo")]
        [Range(0, 1)]
        public int Status
        {
            get { return status; }
            set { status = value; }
        }

        [StringLength(15)]
        public string Numero
        {
            get { return numero; }
            set { numero = value; }
        }

        [StringLength(80)]
        public string Bairro
        {
            get { return bairro; }
            set { bairro = value; }
        }

        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Endereco
        {
            get { return endereco; }
            set { endereco = value; }
        }

        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Cidade
        {
            get { return cidade; }
            set { cidade = value; }
        }

        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "E-mail deve estar preenchido")]
        [StringLength(250)]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "E-mail em formato inválido.")]
        public string Email
        {
            get { return email; }
            set { email = value; }
        }

        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Nome deve ser preenchido")]
        [StringLength(200)]
        public string Nome
        {
            get { return nome; }
            set { nome = value; }
        }


    }
}
```

Classe Usuario

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Model
{
    [Table("Usuario", Schema = "public")]
    public class Usuario : Pessoa
    {
        private string login;
        private string senha;

        public Usuario(string nome, string email, int status, string login, string senha) : base( nome, email, status)
        {
            this.login = login;
            this.senha = senha;

        }

        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Login deve ser preenchido!")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        [Index("Ix_UsuarioLogin", IsUnique = true)]
        public string Login
        {
            get { return login; }
            set { login = value; }
        }

        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Senha deve ser preechida!")]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string Senha
        {
            get { return senha; }
            set { senha = value; }
        }

    }
}
```

Contexto

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Npgsql;
using System.Data.Entity;
using Model;
namespace DAL
{

        public class BaseContexto : DbContext
        {
            public BaseContexto()
                : base("Teste")
            { }

            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("public"); base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            }

            public DbSet<Usuario> Usuario { get; set; }
        }

}
```

Meu problema está aqui, na tabela foi criado os dados de endereço que nao preciso, tipo cidade, endereço, numero... Como posso tirar esse dados para nao ser mapeados?

Minha tabela usuario:

```
CREATE TABLE public."Usuario"
(
  "Codigo" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"Usuario_Codigo_seq"'::regclass),
  "Login" character varying(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::character varying,
  "Senha" character varying(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::character varying,
  "DtCriacao" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT '-infinity'::timestamp without time zone,
  "Status" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  "Numero" character varying(15),
  "Bairro" character varying(80),
  "Endereco" character varying(100),
  "Cidade" character varying(100),
  "Email" character varying(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::character varying,
  "Nome" character varying(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::character varying,
  CONSTRAINT "PK_public.Usuario" PRIMARY KEY ("Codigo")
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public."Usuario"
  OWNER TO postgres;

-- Index: public."Usuario_Ix_UsuarioLogin"

-- DROP INDEX public."Usuario_Ix_UsuarioLogin";

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "Usuario_Ix_UsuarioLogin"
  ON public."Usuario"
  USING btree
  ("Login" COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

primeiro, se `Usuario` não deve ter todos os campos de `Pessoa`, logo ele não deveria herdar de pessoa.

No seu caso, a abordagem mais interresante é fazer um relacionamento de 1-1 com `Usuario` e `Pessoa`, porem você acabaria com o mesmo problema que você citou.

A sua segunda opção é criar uma classe abstrata que sirva de base para Usuario e Pessoa.:

```
public abstract class PessoaBase
{       
    //Contrutor para heranca para obrigacao da criacao de usuario
    public PessoaBase(string nome, string email, int status) {
        this.nome  = nome;
        this.email = email;
        this.status = status;
        this.dtCriacao = DateTime.Now;
    }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Data Criaçao deve estar preenchida")]
    public DateTime DtCriacao { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public int Codigo { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Status deve estar entre 1 = Ativo ou 0 = Inativo")]
    [Range(0, 1)]
    public int Status { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "E-mail deve estar preenchido")]
    [StringLength(250)]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "E-mail em formato inválido.")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Nome deve ser preenchido")]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}

[Table("Pessoa", Schema = "public")]
public class Pessoa : PessoaBase
{
    public Pessoa()
    {

    }

    [StringLength(15)]
    public string Numero { get; set; }

    [StringLength(80)]
    public string Bairro { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Endereco { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Cidade { get; set; }
}

[Table("Usuario", Schema = "public")]
public class Usuario : PessoaBase
{
    public Usuario()
    {

    }

    public Usuario(string nome, string email, int status, string login, string senha) : base( nome, email, status)
    {
        this.login = login;
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Login deve ser preenchido!")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Index("Ix_UsuarioLogin", IsUnique = true)]
    public string Login { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Senha deve ser preechida!")]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Senha{ get; set; }
}
```

a sua terceira opção, é adicionar uma classe de metadados para `Usuario`.

```
[Table("Pessoa", Schema = "public")]
public class Pessoa
{
    public Pessoa()
    {

    }

    //Contrutor para heranca para obrigacao da criacao de usuario
    public Pessoa(string nome, string email, int status) {
        this.nome  = nome;
        this.email = email;
        this.status = status;
        this.dtCriacao = DateTime.Now;
    }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Data Criaçao deve estar preenchida")]
    public DateTime DtCriacao { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public int Codigo { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Status deve estar entre 1 = Ativo ou 0 = Inativo")]
    [Range(0, 1)]
    public int Status { get; set; }

    [StringLength(15)]
    public string Numero { get; set; }

    [StringLength(80)]
    public string Bairro { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Endereco { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Cidade { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "E-mail deve estar preenchido")]
    [StringLength(250)]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "E-mail em formato inválido.")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Nome deve ser preenchido")]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}

[Table("Usuario", Schema = "public")]
[MetadataType(typeof(UsuarioMetadata))]
public class Usuario : Pessoa
{
    public Usuario()
    {

    }

    public Usuario(string nome, string email, int status, string login, string senha) : base( nome, email, status)
    {
        this.login = login;
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Login deve ser preenchido!")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Index("Ix_UsuarioLogin", IsUnique = true)]
    public string Login { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Senha deve ser preechida!")]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Senha{ get; set; }
}

public class UsuarioMetadata
{
    [NotMapped]
    public string Numero { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string Bairro { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string Endereco { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string Cidade { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Certo entendi, obrigado pela resposta vou utilizar a classe abstrata. Só uma duvida que surgiu, a herança só deve ser usada quando a classe filha vai usar todos os atributos da classe pai?

Comment: @Aprendiz se a classe pai possui propriedades indesejadas na classe filha, então isto desvirtua a herança e possivelmente aponta um problema na modelagem.

Comment: Leia a respeito do Princípio de Segregação de Interface, que corresponde  à letra "I" do SOLID: https://robsoncastilho.com.br/2013/04/14/principios-solid-principio-da-segregacao-de-interface-isp/

Comment: Obrigado, só outra coisa, eu posso herdar uma classe abstract criando outra classe abstract? ou esta errado. 
Exemplo:
`public abstract class PessoaBase{}
 public abstract class Pessoa : PessoaBase {}
`
Pois a classe pessoa também nao deve ser instanciada em meu sistema, apenas herdada.

Comment: @Aprendiz, uma classe abstrata ainda é uma classe, não tem o menor problema em ela herda de outra classe, seja abstrata ou não.

Answer (score 1):

Uma outra alternativa de implementação para o seu caso seria criar uma classe de mapeamento e utilizar o `Ignore` para as propriedades que você não quer mapear para o banco:

Classe de mapeamento:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;

namespace SOpt.Entity
{
    public class UsuarioMapeamento : EntityTypeConfiguration<Usuario>
    {
        public UsuarioMapeamento()
        {
            HasKey(u => u.Codigo).Property(x => x.Codigo).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
            Property(u => u.Login);
            Property(u => u.Senha);
            Property(u => u.DtCriacao);
            Property(u => u.Status);
            Property(u => u.Email);
            Property(u => u.Nome);

            Ignore(u => u.Numero);
            Ignore(u => u.Bairro);
            Ignore(u => u.Endereco);
            Ignore(u => u.Cidade);
        }
    }
}
```

Na sua classe de contexto, será necessário retirar a linha `public DbSet<Usuario> Usuario { get; set; }`, adicionando a nova classe de mapeamento nas configurações do `ModelBuilder`:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace SOpt.Entity
{
    public class BaseContexto : DbContext
    {
        public BaseContexto()
                : base("connectionstring")
        { }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("public");

            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UsuarioMapeamento());

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

Script gerado pelo entity utilizando essa implementação:

```
IF schema_id('public') IS NULL
    EXECUTE('CREATE SCHEMA [public]')
CREATE TABLE [public].[Usuario] (
    [Codigo] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [Login] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Senha] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [DtCriacao] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Status] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [Nome] [nvarchar](200) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_public.Usuario] PRIMARY KEY ([Codigo])
)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [Ix_UsuarioLogin] ON [public].[Usuario]([Login])
CREATE TABLE [public].[__MigrationHistory] (
    [MigrationId] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [ContextKey] [nvarchar](300) NOT NULL,
    [Model] [varbinary](max) NOT NULL,
    [ProductVersion] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_public.__MigrationHistory] PRIMARY KEY ([MigrationId], [ContextKey])
)
INSERT [public].[__MigrationHistory]([MigrationId], [ContextKey], [Model], [ProductVersion])
VALUES (N'201704061249317_Inicial', N'SOpt.Entity.Migrations.Configuration',  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
```